# Linux | Intel AC 8265 | Creating 5GHZ Wifi Network with Hostapd

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, hostapd

I am trying to setup a 5GHZ Wifi Network with Hostapd. The problem is that I cant select a channel because all my  5ghz channels have the no-ir flag, and I can't fix that. I tried every single solution that I found on the internet. I also found a few posts, there people claimed that it is not possible to create a 5ghz network with intel adapters, but on other posts, some people could get it to work.

Network Card: Intel M2 AC 8265

Driver: https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html (the one for the 8265)

Driver is successfully loaded (dmesg):

```
[    6.038802] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.107372] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
```

My current main problem is that "*iw list*" shows me no channel without 'no-IR', that means i cant run in ap mode:

```
Frequencies:
        * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5340 MHz [68] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
        * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
        * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
        * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
        * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
        * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
        * 5480 MHz [96] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
        * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
        * 5745 MHz [149] (13.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5765 MHz [153] (13.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5785 MHz [157] (13.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5805 MHz [161] (13.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5825 MHz [165] (13.0 dBm) (no IR)

Frequencies:
        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
```

Most of the people could solve the problem by setting the country code with iw reg set. At the beginning my country code shown by iw reg get was 00, but i fixed this problem and now it's configured correctly:

```
global
    country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

But nothing changes in 'iw list'. All 5ghz channels are still no-ir.

I also done this settings:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=DE
```

also disabled lar - i red that it is necessary because of intel card:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
options iwlwifi lar_disable=1
```

and set regdomain:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
REGDOMAIN=DE
```

for more information - snippet of output of hostapd debugging:

```
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=DE (DFS-ETSI)
nl80211: 2400-2483 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 5150-5250 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no outdoor)
nl80211: 5250-5350 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no outdoor) (DFS)
nl80211: 5470-5725 @ 160 MHz 26 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5725-5875 @ 80 MHz 13 mBm
nl80211: 57000-66000 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
channel [2] (44) is disabled for use in AP mode, flags: 0x36073 NO-IR
wlan0: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (44) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan0: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
```

I don't know what to do anymore; maybe someone has solved this already and can help.

Comment: Any luck? I am trying to do the same thing.